# ASUS touchpad not working properly

Tags: touchpad, asus, multi-touch

I have an ASUS K510UQ Laptop running Ubuntu 17.10. Ever since I installed Ubuntu, I have been having issues with the touch pad. The touch pad very frequently detects double taps when I do a single tap and then starts dragging things around if I move the mouse. I also noticed that the f9 key used for enabling/disabling the touch pad does not work. Some of the mulit-touch gestures do not work either.

Here is the output of `xinput --list` for the touch pad while using the Xorg server (not wayland):

```
FTE1200:00 0B05:0501 Touchpad               id=13
```

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

UPDATE:
Here is the output of `xinput list-props 13`

```
Device 'FTE1200:00 0B05:0501 Touchpad':
Device Enabled (142):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (144): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
Device Accel Profile (269): 1
Device Accel Constant Deceleration (270):   2.500000
Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (271):   1.000000
Device Accel Velocity Scaling (272):    11.061152
Synaptics Edges (273):  48, 1162, 44, 783
Synaptics Finger (274): 25, 30, 0
Synaptics Tap Time (275):   180
Synaptics Tap Move (276):   64
Synaptics Tap Durations (277):  180, 180, 100
Synaptics ClickPad (278):   1
Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (279):  0
Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (280):    282
Synaptics Two-Finger Width (281):   7
Synaptics Scrolling Distance (282): -29, 29
Synaptics Edge Scrolling (283): 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (284):   1, 1
Synaptics Move Speed (285): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.136519, 0.000000
Synaptics Off (286):    0
Synaptics Locked Drags (287):   0
Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (288):   5000
Synaptics Tap Action (289): 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2
Synaptics Click Action (290):   1, 3, 2
Synaptics Circular Scrolling (291): 0
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (292):    0.100000
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (293): 0
Synaptics Circular Pad (294):   0
Synaptics Palm Detection (295): 1
Synaptics Palm Dimensions (296):    10, 200
Synaptics Coasting Speed (297): 20.000000, 50.000000
Synaptics Pressure Motion (298):    30, 160
Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (299): 1.000000, 1.000000
Synaptics Resolution Detect (300):  1
Synaptics Grab Event Device (301):  0
Synaptics Gestures (302):   1
Synaptics Capabilities (303):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0
Synaptics Pad Resolution (304): 12, 12
Synaptics Area (305):   0, 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Soft Button Areas (306):  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Noise Cancellation (307): 7, 7
Device Product ID (266):    2821, 1281
Device Node (265):  "/dev/input/event16"
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput list-props 13` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I've edited the question.

Comment: Install `libinput`.

Comment: Ok, I've installed it. The annoying double tap detection seems to have reduced a little. I'll have to use it for sometime to know if the issue is fixed. Thanks for your help!